# (How) Can I control audio Line-In on an Android x86 computer?

Tags: android, audio, input, x86, line

I have a computer which is installed with Android x86 4.4-r2 and I have to control (i.e. mute/unmute) one of both line input channels. The computer has a [H81M-ITX](http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/H81M-ITX/) motherboard and the Line-In channel I need to control is the rear connector (blue jack). I just cannot locate any Line Input channel control in Android SDK, most probably, I guess, because it was not intended to run on anything else than a controlled hardware with known audio inputs and outputs.

I need to mute/unmute the channel from an Android App. What's the most straightforward way? Code it with the framework or run an external process, i.e. `alsa_amixer` with the right parameters?

Comment: Pardonne-moi for this question, I'm not familiar with Android use but in a smartphone but... Do you have root access on your Android installation in the case you wanted to mess up with `/proc/asound` or `/dev`? Anyway `alsa_mixer` seems promising

Comment: Yes, I do. Android x86 comes with a terminal app that allows for root access.

Comment: Have you tried looking inside `/dev` to get a starting point? I have found [alsa-utils](https://github.com/voku/external-alsa-utils) on github that have and `android.mk` for compiling with NDK but I don't know if it is a dead end street.

Comment: Just curious, why dig /dev? So far I could figure out how to control the mixer state using `alsa_amixer` (using the right sound card ID, of course) so didn't invest more on /dev. Do you have any particular hint to share? As for the github project, most probably just works but it's just another command-line tool set. Makes me believe my second option (external commands) is the most sensible way, right?

Comment: In case `alsa_mixer` would be to hard to install. I found that you can do a lot of fun things digging `/dev` on my rooted phone. Alas I have no experience with audio devices. What's wrong with external commands? You can launch them from your app can't you?

Comment: Don't make me wrong, there's nothing wrong with running external commands and I'm perfectly comfortable with that (read: *enthusiast*). My point is I already have external tools to do what I want so I don't really *need* another one. I was in fact wondering if Android API does also support something else than just one microphone and one speaker, e.g. controlling line input jacks on foreign hardware.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81709/discussion-between-knm241-and-nasha).